# Wildcard bean loading in JBoss 5.1.0.GA

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

We have this in config.xml, which loads OK in JBoss 4.2.2.GA

```
<import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/apollo/babel-*-beans.xml"/>
```

However in JBoss 5.1.0.GA, it does not load (as I am aware things are stricter)

```
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/catalog-config.xml]; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Could not resolve bean definition resource pattern [classpath*:/META-INF/apollo/babel-*-beans.xml]; 
nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:
```

I followed the advice here http://community.jboss.org/message/6502 to disable validation,

```
%JBOSS_HOME%/server/< serverName>/deployers/ear-deployer-jboss-beans.xml, uncommentthe commented out lines: 
<property name="useValidation">false</property>
```

but the error stays.

So how do I make JBoss 5.1.0.GA less strict and able to load using wildcard?

Comment: @skaffman config.xml is just the xml that contains babel-*-beans.xml

Comment: Yes, but what *are* these files? JBoss Beans files, or Spring, or what?